# How do you get the URL of a created Google Doc?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Currently I'm working on a rails app and would like to automate one of the manual processes that are being performed. Right now we currently manually create a google doc, copy the link, and send that out to people. What I would like to do is have a button that creates a google doc (this is done), and once that google doc is created grab the URL from it. What I am having trouble with is figuring out how or if you can even do that once you are navigated away from the app.

I have tried to look for some gems but none of them look to do what I want. I know you can easily get the URL in JQuery, but I'm just stuck on how to access the 'correct' page.

If you need more details I will try to explain better, but I can't post the majority of code.

Thank you.

Comment: surely whatever sdk or api you use to create doc returns it's url in response?

Comment: I'm not using any api, just using the https://docs.google.com/document/create path.

Comment: If you manually go that url it's not clear what your issue is.